# PHPMailer suddenly stopped sending HTML-based emails

Tags: html, phpmailer

Need assistance on something I think should be a simple fix . I am using a PHP Mailer app on my website hosting, which is Network Solutions, I know, shame on me. Very recently Network Solutions stopped sending my HTML-encoded emails for some unknown odd reason. Using their PHP mail testing application, those emails with non-HTML are working and sending just fine, but as soon as I try to send one with HTML(isHTML=True) encoding, it never sends, but I also don't get an error. The program tells me the email was sent successfully.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Hi, I recommend you to add any details you can provide, like PHP mailer version etc. Also try to recreate the issue with the minimum possible code for us to check. I think it's very hard for us to point any possible issue with the amount of information provided

Comment: You need to show your code, and the debug output with `SMTPDebug = 2`.

Comment: Ok silly question; where do I put that code?  I place it inside my php code and I get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in

Comment: When I try to post the code, I get this response and can't figure out a way around this?  Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Now I am getting somewhere.  Upgraded php from 5.6 yo 7.4 and now getting this error: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 553 5.0.0 <custserv@networksolutions.com... Unbalanced '<' 500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: "Content-Type:text/html>" in

Comment: How do I post the code in here without an error?

Comment: What I would really like to do is try the new PHPMailer either v5.6 or v6.x and give it a try.  However I am on a shared windows hosting platform so I do not have a command-line access as in linux.  Anyone available to assist with a manual upgrade of the PHPMailer program?  I looked at the documentation, and it really doesn't help me much with a manual upgrade.  It also refers to files like PHPautoloader.php that do not exist on my system or even in the downloaded code.  I am really stuck here!